# CurrentProductService returns null on PDP page in SSR mode

Tags: spartacus-storefront

We use CurrentProductService on PDP page and from time to time it returns null in SSR mode. I don't understand what it depends on but if we reload page few times product will be returned from this service. Do you have any ideas?

If we use setTimeout with delay 1000 it will work correctly but it's a very bad solution:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.product$ = this.currentProductService.getProduct();
}, 1000);
```

Spartacus Version: 3.4.2

Comment: Can you describe in what context are you using the service?
Which page are you trying to render?
Did you manage to reproduce it on OOTB Spartacus? Is there a custom code involved?

Comment: @pegasus I call CurrentProductService on Product Detail Page in my custom component (my component extends spartacus ProductIntroComponent) like this: `product$: Observable<Product> = this.currentProductService.getProduct();`. I can't reproduce it on OOTB (spartacus public stand) 'cause SSR is disabled there.

Comment: It would be good to try to reproduce the issue on OOTB Spartacus in order to rule out the source code. You can clone Spartacus repo, install dependencies and run `yarn start`, and try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: It's reproduced only in SSR mode. And also we use lazy load modules. I've cloned SPARTACUS repo and tried build app in SSR mode (branch release/3.4.2) on OOTB. SSR doesn't work locally. Maybe should I make some shanges in config?

Comment: What do you mean by "SSR doesn't work locally"? What kind of error are you getting? Or maybe you see CSR instead of SSR?

Comment: Yep, I see CSR and  when look at the code in a browser I don't see transfer state and any rendered components

Comment: Not sure how you tried to run it, but please try the following: `yarn build:libs && yarn build:ssr && yarn serve:ssr:dev`. This will build the libs, the ssr app and start it on `http://localhost:4000`. To check if ssr is working, you can run `curl http://localhost:4000 > home.html`, and then inspect the created `home.html` for the proper ssr content.